# dotnet blazor web assembly template - where is it?

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I have .NET Core 3.1.102 SDK installed and installed the following set of templates via the cli

`dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.2.0-preview1.20073.1`

However, the reported list of templates is as follows

[image]

the blazorserver template is there, but where is the preview web assembly template?

Comment: I have __blazorwasm__ in that list. Not clear what went wrong on your side, trry installing/repairing again. Maybe restart yyour PC first.

Comment: Restarted, but no change. How do I uninstall the templates? I tried `dotnet new -u Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.2.0-preview1.20073.1`, but that just says `Could not find something to uninstall called 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates'`

Comment: And __re__-installing? I would start with the SDK. This is the best guideline i know of: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-1-release-now-available/

Comment: Yes, that was the blog post I originally followed. Just uninstalled versions of VS and all existing .NET Core SDK's. Re-installed just the latest SDK (3.1.102) and then the preview templates as detailed in that blog, but the same result. No `blazorwasm` (restarted a number of times too). Not sure what I'm doing wrong or what else I can do. Can I ask - are you running `3.1.120` SDK and `3.2.0-preview1.20073.1` templates?

Comment: `dotnet --info` tells me .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.200-preview-014977
 Commit:    ca5522cead

Comment: I do have the VS2019 preview installed, once upon a time that was required for  Blazor Client. But it shouldn't be needed now.

Comment: okay, so it was a problem with my nuget sources. I was using a third-party package source (DevExpress, which I had previously uninstallled) but `nuget.targets` was still trying access a directory for that third party application so the template installation was failing. Removing the third part nuget source has resolved the issue.

Comment: You could post that as a self-answer. This may happen to others as well.